# jQuery Tabs inside another jQuery Tabs - OnActivate event

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui

I have a parent Tab that contains another Tab control inside.

Meanwhile I'm catching the `tabsactivate` event from the parent Tab:

```
$('#main').on('tabsactivate', function (event, ui) {
    ...
});
```

And I noticed that everytime the child tab control is activated the parent event is raised also.

This is an expected behaviour I assume, but why? And is there anyway to disable it?

Working example : http://jsfiddle.net/x6Bc9/

Thanks a lot !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can stop the propagation of the child event to the parent

```
    $('#colors').on('tabsactivate', function (event, ui) {
        event.stopPropagation();
    });
```

http://jsfiddle.net/x6Bc9/1/